# Update streets in database from STR to STREET

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a database with all the streets from a certain city. But the names are abbreviated at the end, example: Highwaystr instead of Highwaystreet.

I want all these streets to update at the same time.

I tried this:

```
UPDATE bestrating SET STRAATNAAM = '%STREET' WHERE STRAATNAAM LIKE '%STR'
```

But this is replacing all the street names with "%Street".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's just changing the text at the end, then simpler is:

```
UPDATE bestrating SET STRAATNAAM = STRAATNAAM +'EET' WHERE STRAATNAAM LIKE '%STR'
```

The only places that the wildcard syntax used by `LIKE` is applicable is in `LIKE` and `PATINDEX` (and possibly some of the FTS predicates - I don't use it). It's not supported in the `SET` clause of an `UPDATE`, and SQL Server has no direct support for e.g. regular expressions.

---

The above works provided that the searched for text is a prefix of the replacement text. If that wasn't so, you'd doing something like:

```
UPDATE bestrating
SET STRAATNAAM = SUBSTRING(STRAATNAAM,1,LEN(STRAATNAAM)-LEN('STR')) +'STREET'
WHERE STRAATNAAM LIKE '%STR'
```

I.e. reduce the length of the string by the length of the searched text, and then apply the entire replacement string.

Answer (score 3):

use `REPLACE`

```
UPDATE bestrating 
SET STRAATNAAM = REPLACE(STRAATNAAM, ' STR', ' STREET') 
WHERE STRAATNAAM LIKE '% STR'
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/972f9/1)

Comment: May replace occurrences of `' STR'` in places other than at the end of the text, however. E.g. `UPPER STRING STR` would become `UPPER STREETING STREET`

Comment: I've given an example in my comment. If the string *does* end with `' STR'`, then *all* occurrences of `' STR'` in the string (whether at the end or not) will be affected by your `REPLACE()` call.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever let me update it. just read the comment